# Visual Studio Website Debug Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, web-applications

I'm working on a few pages on a university website. As such, there are a lot of scripts, stylesheets, images, etc. that I have to pull from places where other people are updating them. All these includes are incorporated into HTML snippets that I'm pulling into an MVC layout page. Problem is, all the paths within those look like this: `src="/oit/includes/foo.css">`. We use a couple different servers here and there, so I guess that's for portability across servers, subdomains, whatever. That code isn't mine. The point is, when I want to debug my site, it's not going to find `localhost:1337/oit/includes...` etc. Is there a way to make the debugger think my page is on the university web server, or am I going to have to publish this every time?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly reference the resource from the correct server instead of using relative urls:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://someserver/oit/includes/foo.css" />
```

Comment: The natural option, except that the code can't be edited because they're cross-page HTML snippets made and maintained by another department entirely.

Comment: So let the other department do it if you can't.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve actually. You seem to have some department that produces wrong code and you want it to work although you have no control over it. I don't know how to help you in this situation.

Comment: So copy all the resources to your local env.